# How to insert footnotes in ioslides presentations using RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, ioslides

I created a ioslides presentation by using the `knitr` package and it works well. Now I want to insert footnotes on my slides. I did not find any useful posts on SO. Can anyone show me how to add footnotes on R slides? Any idea?

Here is the dummy  code chunk:

```
---
title: "R presentation"
author: "me"
date: "March 9, 2017"
output: 
    ioslides_presentation
---

## slides one
 * content
 * introduction
## Content
- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

Comment: Do you mean real footnotes or a footer which is the same for all slides?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer not really, I could insert footnotes on the first or other specific slides only. Any idea?

Comment: The pandoc way to add footnotes is `^[footnote text]` http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#footnotes ; however, it doesn't work with ioslides, I don't know why, so I'm afraid you'll need to add them manually in html

Comment: @scoa can I do that with `knitr` ?  Rstudio alarmed me to load all required package for rendering R presentation, `pandoc` is installed. Do you mind to share your thought with demo code?

Comment: Yes you can, since knitr uses pandoc, but only with output format other than ioslides... Otherwise, you need raw html and maybe should tag your question with <html> to get good answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here is a workaround. It might not be bullet proof and need further improvements:**

---

### Let's start with a fully reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Footnotes"
author: "Martin Schmelzer"
date: "9 3 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<style>
div.footnotes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('slide:not(.backdrop):not(.title-slide)').append('<div class=\"footnotes\">');

    $('footnote').each(function(index) {
      var text  = $(this).html();
      var fnNum = (index+1).toString().sup();
      $(this).html(text + fnNum);

      var footnote   = fnNum + ': ' + $(this).attr('content') + '<br/>';
      var oldContent = $(this).parents('slide').children('div.footnotes').html();
      var newContent = oldContent + footnote;
      $(this).parents('slide').children('div.footnotes').html(newContent);
    });
  });
</script>



## Try out some footnotes

Lets assume I have a footnote <footnote content="The first awesoem footnote!">here</footnote>. And here we are going to have another one: <footnote content="This is my second footnote!">#secFN</footnote>


## The Second Topic

See auto numbering for <footnote content = "The counter is not set back and continues on the next slide.">footnotes</footnote>
````

### Now let's see what I have done here:

**1.** We add some styles for our footnote container at the bottom of each slide.

**2.** We include the jQuery library.

**3.** What then follows is the main script:

When the document has finished loading (`document.ready()`) we select all slides excluding the title slides and the back drop slide. To each of them we add a footnote container (`<div class="footnotes"></div>`) as the last child.

Afterwards we simply go through the document and search for our footnotes which can be created the following way:

```
<footnote content="What should be written at the bottom?">Text</footnote>
```

We select all footnotes and apply a function to each of them which reads out the content of `footnote` and adds it to the container. The footnotes get autonumbered and the superscripts are added with `sup()`.

---

### This is what the result looks like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you, Martin. Happy to learn Rmarkdown, cheers :)

Comment: This just fixed a problem with my implementation, where footnotes were sliding around (rather than staying fixed to slides). Thanks for contributing it, Martin!

Answer (score 11):

[Martin Schmelzers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697008/3506011) is great, but I was lacking the possibility of formatting text in the footnote (i.e. make text italic or bold for correctly formatting literature references).

I updated his example to allow for this. See the reproducible example below. Footnotes are added like:

```
<footnote>A *footnote* with **formatting**</footnote>
```

[image]

````
---
title: "New footnotes"
author: "Emil Tveden Bjerglund"
date: "August 8, 2017"
subtitle: "Inspired by Martin Schmelzer"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
<style>
div.footnotes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('slide:not(.backdrop):not(.title-slide)').append('<div class=\"footnotes\">');

  $('footnote').each(function(index) {
    var text  = $(this).html();
    var fnNum = (index+1).toString();
    $(this).html(fnNum.sup());

    var footnote   = fnNum + '. ' + text + '<br/>';
    var oldContent = $(this).parents('slide').children('div.footnotes').html();
    var newContent = oldContent + footnote;
    $(this).parents('slide').children('div.footnotes').html(newContent);
  });
});
</script>

## Testing footnotes
Some text.<footnote>And a footnote. http://stackoverflow.com</footnote>

Some more text.<footnote>And *another* **footnote**</footnote>
````

Comment: Thanks for your contribution